# webview not rendering on ios device

Tags: ios, xamarin, webview

I am facing issues in loading the webview in ipad/ios device.

1. I have created a xamarin cross platform app from visual studio on windows 10 platform, where android and ios build both are available.
2. after app creation, i have created a build for android in mobile as well as checked in simulator, the webview is working perfect.
3. i created .ipa file and installed the app in ipad(In ios simulator it was working in debug mode).
4. in release mode i am directly debugging through my device and buttons are rendering but webview are not visible at all.

FYI

i am doing an api call which is returning html content and using "htmlwebviewsource" trying to load the html in ipad.

here is the code snippet in mainpage.xaml for webview:-

```
                <WebView x:Name="webView"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 Visual="Material"
                 HeightRequest="1000"
                 WidthRequest="1000"
                 IsVisible="False"
                 Grid.Row="2"  
                 Grid.RowSpan="5" 
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
             </Grid>
      </StackLayout>
```

here is the code snippet in mainpage.xaml.cs:-

```
                var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
                Button btn = (Button)sender;
                htmlSource.Html = CreateApiHeader(btn.ClassId);
                webView.Source = htmlSource;
                webView.IsVisible = true;
```

what kind of code level changes i needs to do so that webview starts rendring on my ipad/ios or am i missing something in all the points to make it possible.

Comment: Hi, in release model , could you have a check whether receiving html data from api ?

Comment: yes, i guess it is coming in format.

Comment: OK , could you share the sample project link here , I will check it in my local site .

Comment: i am sorry , i can't.

Comment: OK , got it . I have tried [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithwebview/) , there is no problme .